# How applications show notifications when they are force closed

Tags: android, notifications

I'm trying to understand how android apps can show notifications without being launched. (even after force close)

Is there only a way with firebase or other cloud message services? (push notifications)

Now I'm thinking about alarmmanager, but it not work if app is force closed.

Comment: you need a service to do that. because that will work always. even if you force close your app.

Comment: but service in separate thread will show big text line about "service is active bla bla", i haven't seen something like that in modern apps. 
thats why i'm interested

Comment: @Vadim if you want your service in `foreground` than only it would require you to place a notification, but if you want your service just to send notification, you can just return `Start_Sticky` in `onStartCommand` of your `service` and it would do it's job just fine, even if your app is closed.

And `Service` runs in MAIN THREAD.

Comment: @Michal_196 first it need to download some data, so it can not be on Main Thread.

Comment: You can use `ExecutorService` in your `Service` to download data.

Comment: @Michal_196 and service will be in separate thread too(from main app, so i can force close app and notifications and jobs will go on)?

Comment: @Vadim No! `Service` will run on `MainThread` but it will run in `background` so even if you close your app it will continue to run. To download data you can use `ExecutorService` in `Service` which runs in a separate thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is registered with any **Broadcast Receiver**, that is the reason app is able to show push notification even the **APP** is force closed. In this case, even the app is force closed, its callback method **onReceive()** is called. This is actually the usual way where **Notifications are generated.** As far as alarm manager is concerned that is not app dependent. It is registered on OS level. Once alarm manager is registered, it does not care weather the app is running or force close. Alarm manager calls its **PendingIntent**, that was registered when alarm manager was created. And that **PendingIntent** is responsible for start App components like Service or any **Broadcast Receiver**.Hope that helps you in your understanding.

Comment: Does it mean that i can create Alarmmanager and Broadcast Receiver to show notifications and do some job periodically? 
Because now i only see, that alarm is triggered and nothing happens when app is fully closed.